# multiplication of nonzero scalar in a constraint of the primal

Tags: linear-programming

Suppose we have primal and its dual in standard form, that is

\begin{align*} 
(P) \max z = cx \\
st \; \; Ax = b \\
\; \; \; x \geq 0 \\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*} 
(D) \min z = by \\
st \; \; yA \geq c \\
\; \; \; y \; \; \; free \\
\end{align*}

Where $A$ is an $m $ by $n$ matrix an $x$ is an n vector and $y$ is an m vector.

Suppose we multiply one of the constraints of the primal by some number $\alpha > 0$. Does this affect the solution of the dual?

### Thoughts:

Since a constraint is of the form $a_{ij} \cdot x $, take one of the $i's$, say we multiply

$$ a_{i1}x_1 + a_{i2} x_2 + ... + a_{in} x_n $$

by $\alpha $

Once we set up our tableau, once we divide this row by $\alpha$, then in the LFH, we would have

$$ \frac{ b_i}{\alpha} $$

the ith component of the vector $b$. Doesnt it change the solution in the primal tableau? Since solutions are the same for primal and dual???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplication by a non-zero scalar is equivalent to multiplication of an elementary matrix, $E$.

\begin{align*} 
(P') \max z = c^Tx \\
st \; \; (EA)x = (Eb) \\
\; \; \; x \geq 0 \\
\end{align*}

The dual is
\begin{align*} 
(D') \min z = (Eb)^Ty \\
st \; \; y^T(EA) \geq c \\
\; \; \; y \; \; \; free \\
\end{align*}

Suppose $w$ is the original dual solution, then $y=E^{-T}w.$

For the operation of multiplication by a scalar, we have $E^T=E$.

Hence $y=E^{-1}w$. That is if we multiply $\alpha$ to the $i$-th constraint, now for the dual solution, we would divide $w_i$ by $\alpha$ and we can keep the rest to be the same.

Comment: Can you help me with this related problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2989440/changes-in-the-primal-and-dual-that-modify-the-solutions?noredirect=1#comment6169741_2989440

Comment: at first glance, it seems that doing that operation might cause the primal problem to become infeasible.

Comment: But isnt it doing the same operations as the previous case but this time to the dual?

Comment: the duality is in inequality form, multiplying an inequality and adding it to another one might change the feasible set.  Also, if you multiply by a negative number, the inequality get flipped.

Comment: You are right :/

Comment: Sorry for asking too much, but how would you conclude so fast that the new problem must be infeasible ??

Comment: I wouldn't say it must be infeasible, but there are such cases. We can see that $b$ is in the cone generated by columns of $A$ for the original problem. We are changing the problem without changing $b$, and $b$ need not reside in the cone in the new columns.

Comment: but, the primal solutions stays the same unchanged because it is standard form. So, the only problem is in the dual

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85524/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-neymar).